# Given H is positive definite Hermitian matrix, how to prove that there is some $\alpha>0$ such that $x^{*}Hx \geq \alpha. \vert x \vert ^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let H be a Hermitian positive definite matrix. Prove that there is $\alpha>0$ such that $x^* Hx \geq \alpha \vert x \vert^{2}$ for any $x\in \mathbb{C}^{n},$ where $\vert . \vert$ is euclidean norm on $\mathbb{C}^n.$

I used some diagonalization theorems but at the end I reached the inverse of the above inequality. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: H's smallest eigenvalue satisfies $\lambda >0$. Take a look at $H-\mu\operatorname{id}$, it's still positive-definite for which $\mu$-values?

Comment: It will be positive semidefinite for the smallest positive eigenvalue. But how to show this?

Comment: Yep, but more important is that here's a gap *between*
$\lambda$ and zero. Do you see which direction this could take?

Comment: Sorry I could not see now.  So what does this gap give us?

Comment: It gives some values for $\mu$ to play around with. My intention was to give hints for "Doing it yourself", but I didn't want to write a complete answer. By now, you have two answers, and the one starting with "Another possibility" is in the spirit of looking at $\,H-\mu\operatorname{id}$. By the way, having received answers you should consider up- / downvoting, and possibly (but not immediately) accepting an answer, cf [someone-answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

$H$ is diagonalizable, hence there is an orthonormal basis $u_1,...,u_n$ of $ \mathbb C^n$ consiting of eigenvecors of $H$. Let $\lambda_1,..., \lambda_n$ the corresponding eigenvalues. We can assume that $0<  \lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le ..... \le \lambda_n$.

Now let $x \in \mathbb C^n$. Then $x= \sum_{k=1}^n(x,u_k)u_k$

(where $( \cdot, \cdot )$ denotes the usual inner product on $ \mathbb C^n$).

Then we have:

$Hx= \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k(x,u_k)u_k$

and

$x^{*}Hx =  \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k|(x,u_k)|^2 \ge \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_1|(x,u_k)|^2=\lambda_1 \sum_{k=1}^n |(x,u_k)|^2= \lambda_1 |x|^2$.

$ \alpha = \lambda_1$ will do the job !

Answer (score 1):

Define $f : \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb R $ by $f(x)=x^{*}Hx$ and let $K=\{x \in \mathbb C^n: |x|=1\}$. Since $K$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, we have that

$$\alpha:= \min f(K)$$

exists. It is now your turn to show that $ \alpha >0$ and that

$$x^{*}Hx \geq \alpha \vert x \vert ^{2}$$

for all $x \in \mathbb C^n$.

Comment: Thank you Fred. Showing that alpha is strictly bigger than zero is done by assumption saying H is positive definite, but the second one I could not see. We first worked on K and the desired result is for any x in C^n.How?

Comment: Let $x \in \mathbb C^n$ and $x \ne 0$. Then $z:= \frac{x}{|x|} \in K$, hence $f(z) \ge \alpha.$ Next we need: $f(z)=\frac{f(x)}{|x|^2} .$ Can you proceed ?

Comment: Yeah I can follow what you wrote. I understand it completely.good solution. Thanks. But what about linear algebra methods. I am trying to understand it through eigen values of H. I think it is more elementary . Do you have any idea about eigenvalue business  what was written above?

Comment: See my second answer !